# Bind DataContext Index to Slider Control Value

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

Is it possible to use the current value of a WPF Slider control (Slider.Value) as an input to a Indexing Binding on another control?

Use case: A collection of items is set as the DataContext for a control, and the slider is used to select which item from a collection is displayed.

```xml
<Slider x:Name="selector" Minimum="1" Maximum="{Binding Count}"/>
<!-- How to grab the value of selector and use as indexer?? -->
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding [??????]}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding job}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the current value of a WPF Slider control (`Slider.Value`) as an input to a Indexing Binding on another control?

No, not directly. `??????` in `{Binding [??????]}` has to be a compile-time constant.

You could bind to both the `DataContext` and the `Value` property of the `Slider` and use a converter to perform the lookup though:

```
public class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var yourDataContext = values[0] as IDictionary<double, object>; //cast to whatever the type of your DataContext is
        double value = (double)values[1];

        return yourDataContext[value];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:MultiConverter />
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding  Path="." />
            <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="selector" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </StackPanel.DataContext>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding job}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is really good and makes complete sense. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Declare two dependency properties on your data context: `SliderIndex` and `SelectedItem` (you can name them whatever you want, but those are the names I'll use for my answer).

Bind `Slider.Value` to `SliderIndex`. Then use a [`PropertyChangedCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback?view=netframework-4.8) to update the `SelectedItem` property based on the new value of `SliderIndex`. Finally, bind `StackPanel.DataContext` to `SelectedItem`.

This is the best way I know of to do this. There is no easy way to bind the two directly since you can't use a variable as an index for collection binding. The other option is to use an `IValueConverter` or `IMultiValueConverter`, but the above is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My intention was to implement this all in XAML so the data-behind doesn't have to reflect or provide mechanisms for the data presentation layer.